# Changing the class of another tag onclick of another link in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

currently revising my code for my menu bar just want to ask on how to change the class of my hr tag wherein whenever I click a link the line below the link will change. Well I'm doing it for my horizontal menu. I've made the some code but I admit I'm not so sure of what I'm doing. Well here's my code so far:

HTML

```
 <div class="menu">
    <table class="menu_item">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#">Events</a>
                <hr class="active" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">Reports</a>
                <hr />
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">Settings</a>
                <hr />
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">Logout</a>
                <hr />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $base; ?>javascripts/anim.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
    .menu{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.menu_item td{
    text-align:center;
    width:25%;
}

.menu_list{
    width:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.active{
    background-color:#330000;
}

a {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:0;
    border:0;
}

hr.active{
    color:#ffff00;
}
```

and the Jquery

```
$("a").click(function() {
  $("hr").click(function (){
      $("hr").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

Well I basically just want it to appear like the tabs on android ICS a little bit. Just a little bit though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what Google ICS looks like, but I think this does what you're asking.

```
$("a").click(function() {
      $("hr").removeClass("active");
      $(this).next().addClass("active");
});​
```

[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/zrys5/) I changed the CSS a bit.

In your code, the `$("hr").click` is unnecessary. The user does not click on the hr tag, only the a tag. Also, you were adding the `active` class to the a tag, not the hr.

Comment: Clean simple and easy solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").click(function() {
 $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I think toggle acts differently based on what I really want to happen. Anyway thanks, I can make use of it anyways. :)

Answer (score 1):

take a look on the give example:

```
$('.menu_item a').each(function(i, e){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('.menu_item hr').removeClass('active');
        $(this).next().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

here is the live working code: http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/EFmvJ/

Comment: Works great but the answer above is much cleaner so I think I'd give him the check and I give you a vote up. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$('.menu a').click(function(){
    //Selects hr tag below a tag and toggle active
    $(this).next().toggleClass('active');
});​
```

But you will also need to change your CSS .active class to the following to change an HR tag color

```
hr.active{
display: block; height: 1px;
border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #ffff00;
margin: 1em 0; padding: 0;
}​
```